Unable to select text in pdf when using l3kernel and lmodern since updating on November 11, 2024
I am having trouble with the latest updates of the MiKTeX system since updating the following packages: latex-tools, ltxbase, miktex-misc, l3kernel. When I compile a doc which uses lmodern package with pdflatex.exe, I can no longer select any specific text in the corresponding pdf. This is not the case when I disable the lmodern package.
I am not sure that the culprit is l3kernel. I did uninstall the November 9 12:52:12 2024 version and reinstalled it but to no avail.
I tried the same MWE on a laptop where I did not install the latest updates (mentioned above), and the text in the pdf file is selectable.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\title{Some title}
\author{Myself
\thanks{Ombu tree drive, 123, Buenos Aires, Argentina}}
\date{16th November 2024}

\begin{abstract}
The aim of this work is to generalize Lomonosov's techniques in order to apply them to a wider class of not necessarily compact operators. We start by establishing a connection between the existence of invariant subspaces and density of what we define as the associated Lomonosov space in a certain function space. On a Hilbert space, approximation with Lomonosov functions results in an extended version of Burnside's Theorem. An application of this theorem to the algebra generated by an essentially self-adjoint operator $A$ yields the existence of vector states on the space of all polynomials restricted to the essential spectrum of $A$. Finally, the invariant subspace problem for compact perturbations of self-adjoint operators acting on a real Hilbert space is translated into an extreme problem and the solution is obtained upon differentiating certain real-valued functions at their extreme.  
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Section}

\section{A second section}
\section{A third section}

\end{document} 

The log file is:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.11.16)  16 NOV 2024 11:39
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**D:/Users/xavier/Documents/UCL/Recherche/Papers/LaTeX_Help/foo1_MWE_test.tex
(D:/Users/xavier/Documents/UCL/Recherche/Papers/LaTeX_Help/foo1_MWE_test.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count196
\c@section=\count197
\c@subsection=\count198
\c@subsubsection=\count199
\c@paragraph=\count266
\c@subparagraph=\count267
\c@figure=\count268
\c@table=\count269
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen141
)
(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+lmr on input line 4
.

(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\ot1lmr.fd
File: ot1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pd
ftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count270
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
) (foo1_MWE_test.aux)
\openout1 = `foo1_MWE_test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OML+lmm on input line 1
2.

(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\omllmm.fd
File: omllmm.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 
12.

(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMX+lmex on input line 
12.

(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\omxlmex.fd
File: omxlmex.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10> on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 12.


[1

{C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}{C:/Users/xav
ier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rm.enc}{C:/Users/xavier
/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathit.enc}]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+lmr on input line 1
5.

(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\ts1lmr.fd
File: ts1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <9> on input line 15.


[2{C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ts1.enc}
] (foo1_MWE_test.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 637 strings out of 473682
 13140 string characters out of 5718700
 396049 words of memory out of 5000000
 23752 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 599273 words of font info for 66 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 35i,11n,50p,1082b,353s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx10.p
fb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx12.
pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi10
.pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10
.pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr12
.pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr17
.pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr6.
pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr8.p
fb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr9.pf
b>
Output written on foo1_MWE_test.pdf (2 pages, 168384 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 57 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

This the log of the second version of the same file but with the \lmodern package commented out:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.11.16)  16 NOV 2024 16:38
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**D:/Users/xavier/Documents/UCL/Recherche/Papers/LaTeX_Help/foo1_MWE_test_Ulrik
e_suggest.tex

(D:/Users/xavier/Documents/UCL/Recherche/Papers/LaTeX_Help/foo1_MWE_test_Ulrike
_suggest.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>

(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pd
ftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count196
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
)
(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count197
\c@section=\count198
\c@subsection=\count199
\c@subsubsection=\count266
\c@paragraph=\count267
\c@subparagraph=\count268
\c@figure=\count269
\c@table=\count270
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen141
)
(foo1_MWE_test_Ulrike_suggest.aux)
\openout1 = `foo1_MWE_test_Ulrike_suggest.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 13.


[1

{C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <9> on input line 16.


[2] (foo1_MWE_test_Ulrike_suggest.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 487 strings out of 473682
 9665 string characters out of 5718700
 395840 words of memory out of 5000000
 23635 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 563906 words of font info for 55 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 35i,11n,50p,1013b,297s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
 <C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\tcr
m0600.pk> <C:\Users\xavier\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi
600\tcrm0800.pk><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/publ
ic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiK
TeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Local/Pr
ograms/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Users/xavier/AppData
/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Users/xavie
r/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><C:/Us
ers/xavier/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pf
b>
Output written on foo1_MWE_test_Ulrike_suggest.pdf (2 pages, 107661 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 54 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

'''

You might want to specify exactly which pdf viewer you are copying text from? Have you tried more than one?

I have tried with both Sumatrapdf and Adobe Acrobat

I suspect it's a viewer change rather than a change in latex, test a pdf built on your old system with the viewer on the new, does cut and paste work then? similarly test a pdf from the new with the viewer on the old

I have no problems with an up to date miktex and adobe reader on windows. Show your log-file. And make also the PDF available somewhere.

There have been no significant changes in the kernel that would impact here, and lmodern is unchanged - so I don't see this is an issue at the TeX side

You can find the pdf document at this link: https://1drv.ms/b/c/f7e8f60aefbc930e/Ee_4PNgU7ftFmnL-EhLtFcIBqB5uVDXJp4HWxhDDgpE3KQ?e=jIgxHx

Do you have the same problem if you use Unicode latin moder fonts? I.e. try to use luatex, no pdftex. And change the font specification in the preamble.

I tried with LuaLatex and with both LuaLatexify and Xetexify

I can't download that without an account.

Sorry, maybe I forgot to give the rights to edit, here the link again:https://1drv.ms/b/c/f7e8f60aefbc930e/Ee_4PNgU7ftFmnL-EhLtFcIBqB5uVDXJp4HWxhDDgpE3KQ?e=9q2EUi

@DavidCarlisle I have compiled the same LaTex file on both laptop and PC and have checked the output pdf on both laptop and PC with both sumatrapdf and Adobe Acrobat (pro, not reader).

yes but have you tried a pdf made on the old machine with the viewer on the new? is it the pdf that has changed, or just the viewer?

@DavidCarlisle Yes, I have been able to copy text from the pdf as compiled with the laptop (which has not been updated) with acrobat Pro on the PC which has been updated with the MiKTeX console.

Ah I see you have made one of the pdfs available can you share the pdf from the same file made on teh old machine as well, to compare. then I would look except i see Ulrike is looking and she is better at this (and has miktex, which I do not)

@DavidCarlisle but I can't look now , only in the afternoon.

@DavidCarlisle Here is a link to the same file but compiled on the laptop (no update of MiKTeX): https://1drv.ms/b/c/f7e8f60aefbc930e/Ed1TJ4b38d9Cjp6BtYf1HIUB-hbPpHcHgKT6AJ5a0Z3Hcw?e=UcW6Eb

sorry but it still asks me to login into one of my accounts and I don't do that for links that I get from the internet.

@UlrikeFischer can you try downloading from this website: http://www.xavier-brusset.net/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/foo1_MWE_test.pdf

@UlrikeFischer This is the link to the file as compiled from my laptop (no update of MiKTeX): http://www.xavier-brusset.net/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/foo1_MWE_test_laptop.pdf

well I can confirm that something is wrong. Add \ExplSyntaxOn\sys_ensure_backend:\pdf_uncompress:\ExplSyntaxOff before documentclass, recompile and show the resulting PDF.

@UlrikeFischer The updated LaTeX file with the above text before the declaration of the documentclass still does not provide selectable text either with sumatrapdf or Acrobat Pro, see file: http://www.xavier-brusset.net/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/foo1_MWE_test_Ulrike_suggest.pdf

your laptop example doesn't use lmodern, but the cmr fonts.

well your PDF has clearly broken ToUnicode value. But it is also clearly not the original PDF as created by miktex, it contains xmp-metadata that has been added by someone else. Did you open it in some special PDF editor or viewer that tried to "improve" the PDF?

@UlrikeFischer sorry, I had commented out the lmoden package, but it still gives a non-selectable pdf. And, no, I did not add xmp-data. I only opened it with both Sumatrapdf or Acrobat Pro v9.0

The uncompressed version is broken too, but it also does not use lmodern, there are only cmr fonts in it. Show the log-file of this compilation.

Ah, ok so that's why there are no lmodern fonts. Well try to rebuild the pdflatex formats in miktex. And then look for the log-file of the format creation (somewhere should be a  ....\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log folder with a pdflatex.log file). But that somewhere for download.

@UlrikeFischer The file's name is now with a 1 at the end.  Does not use lmodern fonts, no selectable text, after building the pdflatex format. I also tried with LuaLatex and Xetex and also after rebuilt both formats in MiKTeX. http://www.xavier-brusset.net/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/foo1_MWE_test_Ulrike_suggest_1.pdf

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

By checking the log-file of the format the culprit was found. For some unknown reason a glyphtounicode.tex from the doc-folder of els-cas-templates was in the texmf tree and was used in the formats instead of the default glyphtounicode.tex:
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/els-cas-templates/doc\glyphtounicode.tex
This file maps all glyphs to U+00A0 (non-break space):
\pdfglyphtounicode{A}{00A0}
\pdfglyphtounicode{AE}{00A0}
\pdfglyphtounicode{AEacute}{00A0}
....

and that breaks the PDF quite thoroughly.
To repair that the file must be removed and the format should be recreated.

Great piece of detective work

This problem should not occur if Unicode fonts were used. As I said repeatedly: the best solution is to strictly leave the 8bit TeX engines once and for all. @DavidCarlisle

@wipet No with unicode fonts you don't get that special problem, but on the other side you don't get with pdflatex problems specific to unicode fonts or luaotfload.  Beside this: as we wrote in the LaTeX news we recommend lualatex for new documents. But we will not drop support for pdflatex. It is used since around 30 years and has millions of users and we won't let them down.

@UlrikeFischer  I wonder if these "LaTeX news" will be read. If GUI programmers will reset default configuration prom pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX (including Overleaf). And if the questions of type "I am LaTeX novice, I have problem with pdflatex" disappear here at tex.sx. That would be progress but unfortunately, I don't really believe that.

Many years, I explicitly say on my lectures about TeX: "If you want to use LaTeX, don't hand me your term paper based on pdfLaTeX, I accept only LuaLaTeX." But more than 50 percent LaTeX term papers includes \usepackege{fontenc} etc. It is like fighting windmills. There are tons materials based on old pdflatex on internet. Therefore, I think it would require a more radical approach.
